# Добавить вывод своих изображений tensorflow

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np 
import mnist #Get dataset  // Тренировочные данные
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Grafical // График
from keras.models import Sequential #ANN architecture
from keras.layers import Dense #The layers in the ANN
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageTk
import PIL


 # load data set // Загружаем тренировочные данные

train_images = mnist.train_images () # тренировка изображений данных 
train_labels = mnist.train_labels () # обучение меток данных 
test_images = mnist.test_images () # обучение данных изображений 
test_labels = mnist.test_labels () # обучение меток данных

   #  Нормализуем изображения от [0, 255] до 
   # [-0,5, 0,5], чтобы упростить обучение нашей сети 

train_images = (train_images/255) - 0.5
test_images = (test_images/255) - 0.5
# Сводим изображения. Сводим каждое изображение 28x28 в вектор 
# размером 28 ^ 2 = 784  для перехода в нейронную сеть 

train_images = train_images.reshape((-1,784))
test_images = test_images.reshape((-1,784))
# Set model
model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=784))
model.add( Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', #(classes that are greater than 2) 
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)
#Train the model
model.fit(
  train_images,
  to_categorical(train_labels), # Ex. 2 it expects [0, 0 ,1,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0]
  epochs = 5, #The number of iterations over the entire dataset to train on
  batch_size=128 #the number of samples per gradient update for training
)

model.evaluate(
  test_images, 
  to_categorical(test_labels)
)
```

Как сюда загрузить изображение image.png, (28 * 28 px), что бы его обработала нейронная сеть и вывести результат(например: Новое изображение: 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша модель ожидает на вход тензор размерности `(N, 784)`, где `N` - число подаваемых на вход сети черно-белых картинок.

Соответственно, чтобы подать на вход одну картинку, размерность должна быть `(1, 784)`.

Вот полный пример полносвязной НС с более удачной архитектурой - точность распознования после 10 эпох обучения около 98%:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10
img_size = (28, 28)
img_size_flat = np.prod(img_size)


def get_image(url, target_size=img_size, convert_to='L'):
    if url.lower().startswith('http'):
        r = requests.get(url)
        url = BytesIO(r.content)
    img = (Image.open(url)
                .convert(convert_to)
                .resize(target_size))
    return np.array(img).reshape(-1, np.prod(target_size))


def predict_digit(img, model):
    return model.predict(img).argmax()      


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, img_size_flat).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, img_size_flat).astype('float32') / 255

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

создаем модель:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

обучаем модель:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

загружаем свою картинку и подаем ее на вход обученной модели:

```
img_tensor = get_image(r"D:\download\2.png")
print(f'image tensor shape: {img_tensor.shape}')
# >>> image tensor shape: (1, 784)
print(predict_digit(img_tensor, model))
# >>> 2
```

---

вывод изображений:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = get_image(r"D:\download\2.png")
plt.imshow(img.reshape(img_size), cmap='gray')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Бонус-ответ:

> Как сделать так чтобы не переобучать ее каждый раз при запуске?

```
model.save(r'c:\temp\mnist_model.h5')
...
model = keras.models.load_model(r'c:\temp\mnist_model.h5')
```

Comment: то есть нужно конвентировать изображение в 28 на 28 px?

Comment: и как сделать так чтобы каждый раз не переобучать сеть?

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N, я вам для этого готовую функцию написал - `get_image()`

Comment: а на вход подается черный фон и белая цифра?

Comment: функция `get_image()` - сама преобразует изображение в черно-белое

Comment: Можно последний вопрос? Как сделать так чтобы не переобучать ее каждый раз при запуске?

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N, дополнил ответ примером сохранения и загрузки обученной модели. PS в следующий раз задавайте отдельные вопросы ;)

Comment: cпасибо сейчас попробую!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104898/discussion-between-e-r-h-a-n-and-maxu).